# Syncing git error in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, team-explorer

When I try to sync my git in Visual Studio Team Explorer, I get the following message `An error occurred. Detailed message: 3 conflicts prevent checkout`

I have X incoming commits

I've tried all I can think of, anyone has any expertise regarding this issue?

Comment: Be sure that you are running VS 2013 Update 4 or better.

Comment: How can I check which update I am running?